WildFly23 base Thread max count
There is a need to monitor the number of threads to see how applications on WildFly use server resources. There is a Status section in the WildFly console where the current number of threads is visible, but there is no thread_max_count parameter.
If you go to the server metrics (http://0.0.0.0:9990/metrics ) then you can detect the base_thread_max_count parameter, which implies the maximum possible number of threads that can be created. I would like to understand where I can edit this parameter, I would appreciate it if you share your experience.
